# .htaccess: how to only rewrite .php URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My rewriterule with a condition is working fine as below:

http://www.sitename.com/index.php?n=text redirects to 
http://www.sitename.com/pages/text

and the page renders properly, however, there is a problem that with the redirected URL the arguments are also added to the URL. So actually in address bar it looks like-

http://www.sitename.com/pages/text?n=text

Could anyone help me on this? The htaccess code is given below.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.*)$
RewriteRule index.php http://www.sitename.com/pages/%1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Ok I'll bite: why do you want to redirect from index.php?n=text to /pages/text? I've seen people do it the other way to get "nice" URLs but what's this in aid of?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to catch "`index.php.*`". Otherwise mod_rewrite only replaces the "`index.php`" part of the URL "`index.php?n=text`" with the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Guss,

From what you suggested, i reconstructed it as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.*)$
RewriteRule index.php.* http://www.sitename.com/pages/%1 [r=301,nc]
```

This doesnt seem to be working either. Can you please elaborate on what you have said?

thank you
aditya

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer, please update (edit) your question indicating the update and comment on Guss's answer.

Answer (score 0):

don´t use the url in the rewrite rule, apache then sends a http 200 code and then the 301...

try sth. like this:

```
RewriteRule (index\.php)(?n=)(.*) /pages/$3 [r=301]
```